# Why would Add fail on a ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am somewhat new to using concurrency and parallel functionality in .net 4.5, so this is probably developer error on my part.

I am trying to do a mathematical intersection test over a `ConcurrentBag` of line segments named `_linkCandidates` using a `Parallel.ForEach`.

If an intersection exists, an integer id field from the `_linkCandidates` element is added to another `ConcurrentBag` named `_linkRemoveIndices`.

```
Parallel.ForEach(_linkCandidates, 
                 new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2},
                 link =>
       {
         if (_gcIntersect.Intersect(link.Lat1, link.Lon1, link.Lat2, link.Lon2))
         {
           lock (_linkRemoveIndices)
           { _linkRemoveIndices.Add(link.Ndx); }
         }
       }
```

I have created a unit test where the results are known and the contents of `_linkRemoveIndices` may be verified.

If I run the code in a single threaded approach by setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`, the unit test passes and `_linkRemoveIndices` contains the expected ids (there will be about 200 elements added to `_linkRemoveIndices`).

If I run the code with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2` or more, the `_linkRemoveIndices` does not contain all of the integer ids for the correct solution (there will be less than 20).

My question is:

What is the correct method of adding items to a `ConcurrentBag` in the body of a `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: You should get the same results disregards of MaxDegreeOfParallelism and even without the lock. I suspect `_gcIntersect.Intersect` of not being thread-safe.Could you show how this method is implemented?

Comment: I agree. Locking around `ConcurrentBag.Add()` is rather against the whole point, but I'm much more curious as to what's going on in that `Intersect` method.

Comment: Hi Ksv3n - I would think that as well, however when I run the code with MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, it returns the correct answer.The Intersection test is a classic vector test for the intersection of two arc segments. Intersect probably does need to be refactored to be thread safe.  I will dig into this further and post my findings.